# 'org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort' is deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

Since Spring boot 2.7.1, `@LocalServerPort` (in the package `org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort`) is deprecated.

What can I use in stead of this annotation?

Comment: You have two separate problems here, one is about the `@LocalServerPort` deprecation warning and the other about the SQL query that doesn't execute. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: For the future if something is deprecated and you want to find the replacement, search for "spring <thing that is deprecated> deprecated", or replace spring with java if it is something from the standard JDK. So in this case *spring LocalServerPort deprecated*. It is not kept a secret, you just need to do a quick one minute search to figure it out.

Comment: @g00glen00b
 second one i just  solve local port issue but that sql exception still  coming.i am using tomcat 10 and in my project i manually removed javax to jakarta for servlet because i am using servlet 5 which will not support javax package.

Comment: @Rajat The problem is that now it's kinda too late to change your question to focus on your SQL issue (as that would invalidate the answers). I suggest creating a new question focusing on the SQL grammar issue. I edited that part out of your question.

Comment: @Gimby - Spring is among the worst documented projects I have ever used. And your suggested search query has this Stack Overflow question as its top result.

Answer (score 26):

Import the below package in your spring boot 2.7.1. use @LocalServerPort for the below-mentioned package.

```
org.springframework.boot.test.web.server
```

You can read about it here in the [2.7.18's Deprecated LocalServer Java API doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.18/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html).
Alternative to use: `org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServer` [Java API Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.18/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/server/LocalServerPort.html)

Once go through you query again for the SQL error.

Comment: Hello, I am using Spring Boot 2.7.1 but I cannot import ```org.springframework.boot.test.web.server```. ```.server``` is not found. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @Jakob Herk I'm getting the same, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 11):

The `org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort` is deprecated.

You can import `org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort`

Answer (score 9):

For everybody looking for a solution:
Simply replace your imports of

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
```

by

```java
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
```

[You can find the current docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/server/LocalServerPort.html)

Answer (score 2):

You may try using `@Value("${server.port}")` to get the port. One thing to note here is since Spring Boot release 2.7.0, @LocalServerPort is moved to the test jar because the Spring Boot team only intended that they be used for tests. However, what Puneet suggests will also work provided that you have the below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can also use an event listener to grab the port once the web server has started. Depending on what you're trying to do this might work, but be aware that they even fires after beans have been created.

```
 @EventListener
 void onWebInit(WebServerInitializedEvent event) {
   int port = event.getWebServer().getPort();
 }
```

The simplest approach here is to use either `@Value("${server.port}")` or what Puneet suggests. Use the import from the test jar. And having the above-mentioned dependency in your pom.xml is vital for this to work.

You can checkout the github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29589) related to this migration.